# Forbid hyphenation of several consecutive words in text

Tags: hyphenation

I am trying to avoid hyphenation over odd pages, and I would like to do it manually: forbid hyphenation of some words.

When I embrace the hyphenated word in `\hbox`, some other adjacent word after re-compilation gets hyphenated, so I need to re-run the compiler several times.

`\hyphenpenalty` and other penalties work for the whole paragraph, but I want to forbid breaking of just several adjacent words.

I know I can embrace every word in `\hbox`, but is there any other option?

Comment: You can try: `\hyphenation{yourword yourword ...}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could enclose every entity separated by a space in an `\mbox` in an automated fashion.  I defined the macro `\nohyphen` which does exactly that.

```
\nohyphen{list of words} -> \mbox{list} \mbox{of} \mbox{words}
```

This also means, that to protect spaces you have to wrap the relevant entry in braces, as in `{$a = b$}`.  Otherwise this would also be split at the spaces an chaos ensues.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_pantlmn_words_seq

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pantlmn_nohyphens:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_pantlmn_words_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_pantlmn_words_seq
   { \mbox { ##1 } ~ }
  \tex_unskip:D
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \nohyphen { m }
 {
  \pantlmn_nohyphens:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \parbox{2em}{%
    overly longish dictionary words {$a = b$}
  }%
}
\quad
\fbox{%
  \parbox{2em}{%
    \nohyphen{overly longish dictionary words {$a = b$}}
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

## Alternative

You can also add words to a list, which should not be hyphenated, when enclosed in `\nohyphen`.  I borrowed the example words from Mico's answer for this.  You can add words in a comma separated list via `\addnohyphen`.  This way you don't need to enclose formulas in braces.  On the other hand, this solution is only practical if you want to suppress hyphenation for a few words only.

The leading `x` is there merely to allow hyphenation of `useful`, because TeX prohibits hyphenation for the first word of a paragraph.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \l_pantlmn_words_seq
\tl_new:N \l_pantlmn_nohyphen_tl

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pantlmn_nohyphens:n #1
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_pantlmn_words_seq { ~ } { #1 }
  \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_pantlmn_words_seq
   {
    \str_case:nVTF { ##1 } \l_pantlmn_nohyphen_tl
     { \mbox { ##1 } ~ }
     { ##1 ~ }
   }
  \tex_unskip:D
 }

\cs_new_protected:Npn \pantlmn_add_nohyphen:n #1
 {
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \tl_gput_right:Nn \l_pantlmn_nohyphen_tl { { ##1 } { } }
   }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \nohyphen { m }
 {
  \pantlmn_nohyphens:n { #1 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand \addnohyphen { m }
 {
  \pantlmn_add_nohyphen:n { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
\addnohyphen{useful,handful}

\fbox{%
  \parbox{1em}{%
    x useful handful helpful {$a = b$}
  }%
}
\quad
\fbox{%
  \parbox{1em}{%
    x \nohyphen{useful handful helpful $a = b$}
  }%
}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Here's a LuaLaTeX-based solution. It consists of (i) a Lua function that encases each word in its argument in an `\mbox{...}` "wrapper" to make it un-hyphenatable, while still allowing line breaks *between* words, and (ii) a LaTeX macro named `\nohyph` that invokes the Lua function. The *argument* of the LaTeX macro should be the string of consecutive words that mustn't be hyphenated.

[image]

```
% !TEX TS-program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function nohyph ( x )
   x = string.gsub ( x , "%a+", "\\mbox{%0}" )
   return ( tex.sprint (x) )
end
\end{luacode}
\newcommand\nohyph[1]{\directlua{nohyph(\luastring{#1})}}

\usepackage[textwidth=1mm]{geometry} % set an extremely narrow measure
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
useful handful helpful
---
\nohyph{useful handful helpful}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why does `luatex` hyphenate the very first `useful`? In Knuth-TeX hyphenation for the first word of a paragraph is not feasible.

Comment: @HenriMenke - Best I can tell, the inability of original-TeX -- as well as the later eTeX, pdfLaTeX, and XeLaTeX -- to hyphenate the first word of any paragraph was simply a bug that, somehow, became a "feature". Fortunately (and probably deliberately!), the creators of LuaTeX decided to get rid of this "feature".

Comment: @HenriMenke -- For more on the topic of LuaTeX being able to hyphenate the first word of a paragraph -- something that Knuth-TeX, pdfLaTeX, and XeLaTeX are not able to do -- see also [Joseph Wright's extensive answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222300/5001) to your query, [What are the incompatibilities of pdftex, xetex and luatex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/222286/5001)

Comment: @Mico ;-) You're cheating ;-)